SwiftData @Model class, switching statements order in init block would surprisingly break the view
I have a simple one-to-many relationship. Playlist and Song.
In the same view, upper section prints playlist.name and playlist.songs array. Array is expected to update when new songs are added.
Inside Song's init block, surprisingly, the order of the two statements breaks the view updating behavior.
    // MARK: - unexpected behavior on switching order
    // To reproduce,
    // 1. click "add playlist", then click "add song"
    // 1. observe the playlist view should update as new songs are added.

    // MARK: the upper playlist view are not updated
    self.playlist = playlist
    self.name = name

    // MARK: switching the order, the upper playlist view are correctly updated
//    self.name = name
//    self.playlist = playlist

It seems to be an bug and I've reported it.
I'm looking to understand this better:

explanations or insights into swift language, macro, etc that how come this could possibly happen.
any workarounds or what's the best strategy to achieve the same
behavior without exposing to this uncertainty.

Full example below:
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
final class Playlist {
  @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Song.playlist)
  var songs: [Song] = []

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

@Model
final class Song {
  var playlist: Playlist?
  var name: String
  init(
    name: String,
    playlist: Playlist?
  ) {
    // MARK: - unexpected behavior on switching order
    // To reproduce,
    // 1. click "add playlist", then click "add song"
    // 1. observe the playlist view should update as new songs are added.

    // MARK: the upper playlist view are not updated
    self.playlist = playlist
    self.name = name

    // MARK: switching the order, the upper playlist view are correctly updated
//    self.name = name
//    self.playlist = playlist
  }
}

struct MyExampleView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

  @Query private var playlists: [Playlist]
  @Query private var songs: [Song]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List(playlists) { playlist in
        Text("\(playlist.name) contains: \(playlist.songs.description)")
      }

      Spacer()

      Button {
        addPlaylist()
      } label: {
        Text("Add playlist")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .bold()
      }
      .background()
      Divider()
      List(songs) { song in
        Text("\(song.name) from: \(song.playlist?.name)")
      }
      Spacer()
      Button {
        addSong()
      } label: {
        Text("Add song")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
          .bold()
      }
      .background()
    }
  }

  func addPlaylist() {
    let newPlaylist = Playlist(
      name: "New Playlist \(Int.random(in: 1...100).description)"
    )
    modelContext.insert(newPlaylist)
  }

  func addSong() {
    let newSong = Song(
      name: "New Song \(Int.random(in: 1 ... 100))",
      playlist: playlists.randomElement()
    )
    modelContext.insert(newSong)
  }
}

#Preview {
  let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
  let container = try! ModelContainer(
    for: Song.self, Playlist.self,
    configurations: config
  )

  return MyExampleView()
    .modelContainer(
      container
    )
    .presentedWindowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    .presentedWindowToolbarStyle(.automatic)
}



For other possible workarounds see this answer



I tried to debug this and check some of the properties added by the @Model macro but I couldn't find anything useful. It's a very interesting (and odd) find that the order of the properties matter or rather that it matters when the relationship is set. I suspect the bug is somewhere deep in the SwiftData code and there is no way we can figure out what it is so we just have to wait for Apple to fix it.


@JoakimDanielson Thanks for looking into this curious case. (I wasn't really sure how reproducible is this bug.)
I'm experimenting with the approaches you linked in other thread. I'm trying to find docs around how @Query and @Relation properties interact manual mutations to them. E.g. how would these manual mutations persist (or discard) without those modelContext.insert() and how are conflicts being resolved.

Switching the order would fix it for one relationship. If the model has multiple foreign key relationship, it'll still fail on those that are not in the last.
The most robust way I found to handle SwiftData relationships is to always create entity first, associate entities later. (and this is possibly due to cloud sync considerations when designing SwiftData)
In this case:
@Model
final class Song {
  var playlist: Playlist? = nil
  var name: String
  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

extension ModelContext {
  func insertSong(
    var name: String
    var playlist: Playlist?
  ) {
    let song = Song(name: name)
    self.insert(song)
    guard let playlist = playlist else { return } 
    // find out if playlists exists (e.g. fetched from modelContext) or newly created (e.g. via Playlist(name: "name")) 
    if let fetched = self.fetchOne(id: playlist.id) {
      // associate song with existing
      song.playlist = fetched 
    } else {
      // insert playlist first and then make associations
      self.insert(playlist)
      song.playlist = playlist
    }
  }

  func fetchOne<T>(id: PersistentIdentifier)
    -> T? where T: PersistentModel
  {
    if let registered: T = registeredModel(for: id) {
      return registered
    }

    var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<T>(
      predicate: #Predicate {
        $0.persistentModelID == id
      })
    fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
      return try fetch(fetchDescriptor).first
    } catch {
      logger.error(
        "Failed to fetchOne for id. Entity name: \(id.entityName) Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
      )
    }
    return nil
  }
}

